# How invoke live method with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning how to write jQuery plugin. So why I am doing what I am doing does not matter.

I writing a plugin called live2 which does nothing else but internally calls live method.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.live2 = function() {

        /* if there are no elements then just return */
        if (!this.length) return this;

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

      jQuery.fn.live.apply(this, arguments);

        }); // end of return this.each(function())
    }; // end of plugin
})(jQuery);
```

Above code should be invoked just live any live method. Instead of live use live2.

```
$('#container').live2('click',function(){
return false;
})
```

But the plugin is not working. Any idea what the fix should be.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You could do this much with just: `jQuery.fn.live2 = jQuery.fn.live;`

Comment: this is the smallest level to describe the problem I am facing while writing a bigger plugin. In some cases I need to invoke the live method and in else case I need to do something. I am stuck where I need to just invoke live and get out.

Answer (score 1):

live only works with a selector, so

`$('#something.something').live(...)` will work

`$(this).live(...`) is not supposed to work (according to documentation)

Your plugin example looks quite ok. Id change this two things:
1. this into $this
2. return after calling each

And live is not a good function to do the experiments with. Try toggle

like this:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.toggle2 = function() {

        /* if there are no elements then just return */
        if (!this.length) return this;

        this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.toggle(arguments);
        }); 

        return this;

    }; // end of plugin
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I think you just need to do this:

```
$.fn.live2 = function() {
    this.live.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a $ in this line:

```
  jQuery.fn.live.apply(this, arguments);
```

Therefore,

```
  jQuery.fn.live.apply($this, arguments);
```